# PHP - How to get a domain age from whois output?

Tags: php, dns, whois

i am trying to calculate a domain age using whois output but mostly whois creation date showing wrong information.

**For example:** i am retrieve whois data for " `alexa.com` " from " `whois.verisign-grs.com` " or " `whois.markmonitor.com` "

the creation date showing " `Creation Date: 2013-10-09` ". 
According the whois data the domain age is " `0 years, 209 days` " old from today!

But it is wrong?? actually, alexa domain age is " `17 years 294 days` " old from today.

please look out the below image on Wrong Information of whois

[image]

Why it is wrong ? How can i calculate domain age?  Totally confused. Help me out...

Comment: My guesses are the creation date must be the date when the domain name was renewed.

Comment: @Shankar Damodaran - there is a updated date above the creation date! so, updated date is domain renewed date.

Comment: The returned information from whois.verisign-grs.com contains the creation date properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the wrong part of the WHOIS data. The correct part, for "thick registry" TLDs like `.com`, is at the top of the response:

```
   Domain Name: ALEXA.COM
   Registrar: MARKMONITOR INC.
   [a bunch more stuff...]
   Updated Date: 10-oct-2013
   Creation Date: 17-jul-1996
   Expiration Date: 16-jul-2018

>>> Last update of whois database: Wed, 07 May 2014 06:30:57 UTC <<<
```

The date you're looking for is the "Creation Date" above: July 17th, 1996.